# Why would client.id created by default with kafka stream application contain random UUID

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

The following are the summary of my understanding of how `client.id` will be created under stream app:

- If `client.id` field is **unset**, then all consumers and producers under the same stream application will have client.id created with the `application.id + UUID`.
- If `client.id` is **set**, then the value will be used instead of the default `application.id + UUID` combo.

However I'm trying to understand the intention behind using the random UUID for the `client.id` field as the default behaviour. As far as I understand, the `client.id` field is an optional user input which is used for logging and monitoring purposes. So removing the UUID from `client.id` by manually setting a value should not break any topology logic or partition assignment.

If my understand of client.id is correct then what is the actual reasoning behind using the UUID as the default behaviour?

Thanks in advance, much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean it'll break something if manually set?

Comment: After I manually set the client.id field, then the UUID will be gone from it. I just wanted to make sure removing the UUID from the client.id field will not cause potential issues such as consumer assignment by kafka.

As far as I know, there is an immutable fielded called `consumer.id` which is created by kafka for each consumer to uniquely identify them. The consumer.id is created using <client.id>+UUID. So it means that even if I'm using the same client.id for all consumers, kafka should still be able to uniquely identify each consumer with the UUID at the end. Just want to confirm.

Comment: There is `group.id` (not `consumer.id`), which is set from the `application.id`, and has no connection to any `client.id`, and the group ID is what controls assignments